# First partition resized after system install and second partition not working

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, operating-systems, data-recovery

I had a problem with my RAM upgrading, I wanted to upgrade from 2 to 4GB and my comp didn't recognize it, so I took it to service and they tried to install Windows 7 x64, and when he run boot he noticed that my second partition, that had all high valuable data is 100% free space...
He installed system on first partition anyhow ( he did quick format of it ), and I tried to recover data with software, but it say that it have "3279 LOST files", that have LOST_FILE_123.ext names, and most of them are not complete, that is total 3,13GB of data... and I can't afford that, since I need those files for my work...

I just noticed that first partition was resized, it was 40,0GB and now it's 47,7GB...
I don't know how this happened, it happened after system boot started and nothing was pressed to allow that...

Also, my second partition, one that had all valuable data is not accessible now...
It looks like first partition STEAL 7,7GB from second partition making it unusable...

Is there anyway to fix this?

Also, this recovery program I have recover all good folders in one folder ( RecoverMyFiles program name ), so that is not good also...

Any suggestion?

Please help...

Comment: I don't know, but when I look at the related questions I see about 10 of the that deal with data recovery from a partition for whatever reason. Are you sure you did not find anything close there to answer your problem?

Comment: Nothing like this... :/

Comment: I don't think anyone can recreate this problem to find out what caused it. Unless someone knows how to reverse this procedure, I strongly suggest looking at all the recovery option and options under "Cure" in @redgrittybrick's post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"[Prevention](https://www.google.com/search?q=backup+software) is better than [cure](https://superuser.com/questions/11160/recover-data-loss-from-accidental-quick-format)" - but I guess you need the latter.

Comment: Okay, I will turn on my time machine now and in past don't go to that service... Okay. Thank you. -.- Like I don't know that now... I created two partitions for that reason, so second partition is SAFE, but whatever he did changed that... I can't backup 100GB of data that is updating periodically except using external HD, and I don't have that... Anyhow, it's done what is done, so what can be done NOW?

Comment: @SharkTheDark: The second link suggests recovery tools. I notice that Recuva is often mentioned in the answers to this sort of question. P.S. "[Time Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_(Mac_OS))" exists on Mac OSX.